# SaveAs appears out of the blue when using keyboard shortcuts in Word 2021 documents

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I've been using Office 2019 (for Windows) until recently, when I upgraded to Office 2021. Since then, I've observed the following behaviour when using Word: **while editing a document (any document), at some point the Save As dialogue window opens randomly.**

By 'randomly' I mean without me having pressed <kbd>F12</kbd> or clicked on Save As in the menus. Instead, I noticed it appears while using the keyboard to navigate through the document, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+arrows to select text; or certain mouse gestures like selecting a paragraph.

I noticed no one keyboard combination or mouse operation that triggers the behaviour reproducibly, but some keyboard shortcut seems to be pressed  at the time of each popup (this could all just be "[superstitious-pigeons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B._F._Skinner#%22%27Superstition%27_in_the_Pigeon%22_experiment)" observations though).

The Save As window goes away upon pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and I can continue working, but this has become annoying.

I found only few other threads reporting this problem (links below), and followed their suggested solutions (except for the clean-reinstall one) - to no avail. I also reinstalled the only Word add-on I have, that for Zotero, also without any change in this behaviour.

This seems to be related then to the 2019->2021 upgrade. Anyone else experienced this, and found a fix?

EDIT: this is not specific to any one document, as it manifests also when I work on other docs

LATER EDIT: it seems the Save As window appears if ANY key at all is pressed during auto-saving. WHy that is remains mysterious, but at least I think I can reliably reproduce the conditions in which this bug manifests.

---

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/save-as-window-keeps-popping-up/e051c42c-fad2-496a-a2f3-aab274d0570d

https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftWord/comments/fdt9o8/word_being_weird_it_keeps_randomly_opening_the/

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/save-as-option-randomly-opening/f46a6cbf-498b-4323-90cc-6564e00024bd

Comment: try to change the autosave folder: it could be that it is locked or that word has no write access. If the save command fails, word will open a save as.. dialogue.

Comment: Have you tried running the Office uninstallation tool and reinstalling Office 2021?  You should also [Verify your Autosave settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-do-i-turn-on-autosave-dbd19b49-ff3a-48f5-8294-671e33a6712c).  Recall that Office 2021 is a specific Office 365 build in time, so some articles about Office 365, will apply to it.

Comment: SaveAs is triggered by the F12 key. Verify that it's not a bit stuck and perhaps triggered by keyboard vibrations.

Comment: I can press F12 and it will trigger Save As, doesn't appear to be a mechanical issue with that key. It does seem to be something about the autosave folder though, set at C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\. If I go to autosave options and click the Browse button next to that folder, then try to create a New|TextFile, it won't do anything. Could it be that Word has no write access there bcs it's not started with admin rights? Nothing was different in my Office 2019 installation, where I had no such random SaveAs windows pop up.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to run Word once as an Administrator and exit immediately.

Comment: Tried that, but doubt it will change anything in my originally reported problem. Also, I was wrong in the prev comment, Word ran as nonadmin does, in fact, have writing rights in the autosave folder - so it's probably not from that

Comment: One more reason I don't think it's from autosave: that is set to 1min on my Word installation, whereas the SaveAs pop-up appears much less regularly, even when I continuously work on a document.

Comment: you should tag people in comments, such as: @z8080 otherwise they won't know you've replied. Will this happen only with old files, or also with files which you start from scratch? It could come from an upgrade to the file format

Comment: Ah yes thank you @1NN, will tag from now on. So far I've been working on old files only, so remains to be seen - but afaik no format upgrades have been made between office 2019 and 2021. Those old docs were all in the latest docx format (no compatibility mode).